# implementing a mutex with capacity

Tags: go, lock-free

Not sure this is the right place, but I'll have a try.

I'm trying to implement a mutex with capacity, which can be achieved easily with buffered channel like this:

```
var ch = make(chan struct{}, 1000)

func Enter(ctx context.Context) error {
    select {
        case ch<- struct{}{}:
             return nil
        case <-ctx.Done():
             return ctx.Err()
    }
}

func Exit() {
    select {
        case <-ch:
             return nil
        default:
    }
}
```

But in order to reduce lock contention, I tried this(https://github.com/zhiqiangxu/util/blob/master/wm/max.go):

```
package wm

import (
    "context"
    "sync/atomic"
)

// Max watermark model, a tmutex with capacity
// The entire point of this module is to reduce lock contention under fast path
type Max struct {
    count   int64         // total number of participators
    entered int64         // total number of entered
    max     int64         // max number of entered, immutable
    ch      chan struct{} // channel for exit signal from entered
}

// NewMax is ctor for Max
func NewMax(max int64) *Max {
    m := &Max{max: max, ch: make(chan struct{}, max)}
    return m
}

// Enter returns nil if not canceled
// Enter guarantees at most N callers will enter successfully at any moment, and will wait when overflow
func (m *Max) Enter(ctx context.Context) error {
    count := m.incCount()

    // slow path, wait for exit signal before try
    contendFunc := func() error {
        for {
            select {
            case <-m.ch:
                // someone exited, try enter again
                if m.tryAddEntered() {
                    return nil
                }
                continue
            case <-ctx.Done():
                // ctx canceled, restore count before return
                m.decCount()
                return ctx.Err()
            }
        }
    }

    if count > m.max {
        // too many participators, wait for someone to exit
        return contendFunc()
    }

    if !m.tryAddEntered() {
        // this means there is a sudden burst of participators that entered in very short instant in other goroutines
        // this should happen very rarely
        return contendFunc()
    }
    return nil
}

//go:nosplit
func (m *Max) tryAddEntered() bool {
    if atomic.AddInt64(&m.entered, 1) <= m.max {
        return true
    }

    // recover before return
    m.decEntered()
    return false
}

//go:nosplit
func (m *Max) decEntered() {
    atomic.AddInt64(&m.entered, -1)
}

// TryEnter returns true if succeed
func (m *Max) TryEnter() bool {
    count := m.incCount()
    if count > m.max {
        m.decCount()
        return false
    }

    if !m.tryAddEntered() {
        m.decCount()
        return false
    }
    return true
}

// Exit should only be called if Enter returns nil
func (m *Max) Exit() {

    m.decEntered()
    count := m.decCount()

    // two cases to consider:
    // 1. remaining count < Max
    //      can there be any waiters?
    //      prove that if there are X(<=count<Max) waiters, there must be at least X signals in ch.
    //      suppose there are X waiters,
    //      then they must have tried to enter at a moment when there are at least Max participators or exactly Max entered
    //      consider the last waiter, when its Max entered callers exit, the first X will see the X waiters(Max-i+X>=Max),
    //      so at least X signals will be dilivered.
    //
    // 2. ch is full
    //      will some waiters miss the signal?

    // remaining count >= max
    if count >= m.max {
        // try to wake some waiter up by exit signal.
        // buffered channel ensures never miss any signal
        // the waiter may have been canceled by ctx, but it doesn't matter,
        // superfluous signals only matters for performance purpose
        select {
        case m.ch <- struct{}{}:
        default:
        }
    }

}

//go:nosplit
func (m *Max) incCount() int64 {
    return atomic.AddInt64(&m.count, 1)
}

//go:nosplit
func (m *Max) decCount() int64 {
    count := atomic.AddInt64(&m.count, -1)
    if count < 0 {
        panic("Max: count < 0")
    }

    return count
}
```

As you can see, this file contains more comments than actual code, because correctness is hard to verify, especially the case at Line 105, can someone review it?

Comment: implement mutex with capacity using channels is a good way... could you explain what this code does.. cause I think it can be made simpler.

Comment: Are we talking of [a semaphore](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/semaphore#ex-package)?